# How to generate one single csv from Apache drill query

Tags: apache, apache-drill

I was trying to generate one single csv table from a query in drill, but it turns out that the resulting data folder has multiple csv files with almost equal file size. How should I set the query so that it only generate one single csv file? Thanks!

Below is my script structure:

```
ALTER SESSION SET `store.format`='csv';
CREATE TABLE dfs.tmp.test AS
SELECT tb_left.col1, tb_left.col2
FROM tb_left
LEFT JOIN tb_right
ON tb_left.col1 = tb_right.col1
WHERE tb_left.col2 IS NOT NULL
;
```

Comment: It should generate one csv file. How many records are returned by your SELECT query?

Comment: I tried  **CREATE TABLE dfs.tmp.emplyoee.csv AS SELECT * FROM cp.`employee.json`;** this select query has 1000+ records and it generated 1 csv file.

Comment: @dev About 7 million records with two columns. The query returned 690 csv files, each is about 500KB in size.

Comment: In your case, your each CSV file is having around **10 thousand records, two columns and 500kb size**. so, I tried it with more data.  It returned me **1 CSV file (size 2mb) with 61185 records**.  So, i don't think its a limitation from Drill side.